# Is Bajor's post-occupation economy money-based?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9, money, economics

Other than a single reference to money in [DS9: "Necessary Evil"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Necessary_Evil_(episode)) (which could well be edited away without hurting any story arc), I don't remember the Bajoran economy being portrayed as being based on money as a universal unit of exchange (nor, in fact, on commodity exchange in general).

Is the structure/basis of the Bajoran economy established officially? Is the reference to "Bajoran litas" sound, and based on off-screen canon documents?

I should mention that we don't see any Bajoran bankers, nor Bajoran industrialists, Bajoran "latifundistas" (large land-owners) etc. This insinuates there is little concentration of capital, which would not be the case in a money-based economy (although, granted, that depends on the writers' political views).

Comment: https://memory-beta.fandom.com/wiki/Lita

Comment: @DavidW: If land was for sale, then Bajor was pretty much full-blown Capitalist.

Comment: "Bajoran litas" are also from the episode "Necessary Evil", the transcript [here](http://www.chakoteya.net/DS9/428.htm) has a line from Odo where he says "Interestingly, every one of them has transferred exactly one hundred thousand Bajoran litas into her bank accounts within the last twenty six hours." I don't understand what you mean by "off-screen canon documents" though--nothing off-screen is normally considered 100% canonical in Trek AFAIK.

Comment: @Hypnosifl: I mentioned the episode in the question...

Comment: OK, I thought you were saying that episode has a "single reference to money" (it actually has several lines about money where they don't mention litas) but were asking where the idea of Bajoran using "litas" came from without realizing it came from that episode as well, since you asked if it came from "off-screen canon documents". Apparently I misunderstood, but I'm still not clear why you would want off-screen documents when they presumably wouldn't be as canonical as something actually mentioned onscreen.

Comment: @Hypnosifl: The "show bible", or show-runners' memos, would effectively be canonical.

Comment: "*Darrah hopped a near-empty tram at the foot of the road and took it to the night market at the base of the hill. Hunger always made him terse and short-tempered. He found the first street vendor he came across and handed her a couple of lita coins, getting some savory porli strips in a rough mapa bread roll.*" - Not canon, but litas (as currency) are repeatedly mentioned in various DS9 Extended Universe novels.

Comment: "*“She found a piece of cloth—handwoven, exquisitely rich in color and detail. Seeing that it pleased her, I asked the merchant discreetly for a price—I thought I would surprise her with it as a gift. When he tried to take it away from her, telling her at my request that it wasn’t for sale, she raged at him. ‘How could he deny a soul her burial shroud? Was cruelty to widows part of his way of doing business?’ I paid him the litas you left me and removed her from the shop as soon as I could.”*"

Comment: The strong implication from the novels is that Bajor has a functioning economic system based on the ownership of property, with money as a transmissible means of paying for goods

Comment: In DS9, S4:E15, Bar Association, about 9 minutes in, Leeta (the Bajoran dabo girl) says "I can't afford a pay cut".

Comment: @EmileCormier: She works on DS9, and for a Ferengi.

Comment: @einpoklum But DS9 is a Bajoran space station. Perhaps she spends all her money on Quark's holosuites; I know I would. :-D

Comment: @EmileCormier: "Bajoran"... hah, they wish. It's basically a Federation space station.

Answer (score 9):

#### Probably... maybe?

I have very, very little evidence to go off of, and hopefully someone will be able to post a better answer than this.

My thinking on this is based almost entirely on the *DS9* episodes *Progress* (season one, episode 15), *Shakaar* (season three, episode 24) and *Bar Association* (season four, episode 16). And it's still patchy.

My evidence from *Progress* is as basic and thin as it gets. There is a line from a ship captain that Jake and Nog are trying to bargain with:

> CAPTAIN: I'll give you a hundred gross of self-sealing stem bolts. Some Bajoran ordered them from me, and now he can't pay.

Perhaps not the best evidence, given that the Bajoran *couldn't* pay, but would be pretty brazen to order goods physically transported via freighter without even a possibility of rendering payment. And this captain draws a distinction between paying and trading:

> NOG: And they can be yours for say, five bars of gold-pressed latinum.
>
> CAPTAIN: That's a lot of latinum.
>
> NOG: That's a lot of yamok sauce.
>
> CAPTAIN: Look, I'm not carrying any latinum. But I'll tell you what I'll do. I'll trade you something for it.

This is weak stuff-- but the word *pay* strongly suggests currency rather than barter, even though latinum itself may be a commodity rather than currency (I've never been totally clear on its role in the setting, outside of Ferengi society). But regardless of whether or not the Bajoran stem bolt orderer would have paid in latinum or some other means of exchange, it seems likely that they intended to pay in some form of currency.

This means nothing with regard to the Bajoran economy-- there's no particular reason to think that he would have necessarily been paying in *Bajoran* currency, if such a thing even exists. But season one takes place not too long after the occupation ended, and if the Bajoran intended to pay in money he must have gotten some negotiable currency of some kind from somewhere. Bajor is the best candidate.

---

In *Bar Association*, Quark is upset about the Bajoran Time of Cleansing (during which Bajorans fast and abstain from worldly pleasures) because it has seriously harmed his business. If we assume that Quark is telling the truth about this (which is not necessarily sound, but his bar does appear to be pretty empty), that suggests a couple of things:

- Bajorans make up a substantial portion of Quark's business
- Bajorans on Deep Space 9 have money to spend, demonstrated
  by the fact that they sometimes do so at Quark's

So Bajorans must get that spending money from somewhere. They could, of course, work for non-Bajoran interests which pay them in money-- Quark's dabo girls are frequently Bajorans, and in *Bar Association* they are definitely working for pay. But Bajor is just getting back onto the scene in the Alpha Quadrant after the occupation, and I'm not aware of any evidence that a substantial number of Bajorans are employed in non-Bajoran enterprises. They could be bartering for Quark's services, but I don't know of any evidence for that, either.

There's even a line of dialogue suggesting that Bajorans spend money at Quark's, when Leeta reminds everyone of Quark's loss leader for dabo:

> LEETA: Why don't you try your luck at dabo wheel? Remember, every Bajoran gets one free spin.

*One* free spin for each Bajoran (DS9 resident/worker or not). And since it's a casino game, it won't make any money off of free spins-- people have to make wagers for Quark to have a shot at profiting. And a loss leader offer is an enticement to spend money elsewhere, be it non-free spins of the wheel, food and drink, or holosuites. Therefore it stands to reason that Quark sees opportunity for profitable business with individual Bajorans, generally, suggesting that individual Bajorans have something to offer Quark for his services. The easiest generally valuable thing (to Quark) that any random Bajoran would be able to offer is some kind of money.

This argument is far from iron-clad. Bajorans come to DS9 from Bajor pretty frequently, but we don't know how much of Quark's clientele are such visitors. They could just as easily be primarily people living and working on DS9, getting money from the various interests that pass through the station in an economy largely separated from Bajor's.

But I submit that the easiest and most parsimonious conclusion is that Bajor itself has some sort of economy based around something money-like enough that it can be used reliably for routine transactions, such as eating, drinking, gambling, and enjoying holosuites, to the extent that a business' finances could depend on it.

---

In *Shakaar*, farming is a key element of the conflict driving the episode's plot. In particular there are references connecting the farming both to feeding Bajor's population as well as seemingly little coordination among autonomously governed provinces:

> SHAKAAR: I don't give a damn how the rest of the galaxy looks at us. We're trying to feed our own people here and you're talking about exports.

If the farming conditions being poor (which they are, due to Cardassians poisoning farmland) could lead to a meaningful lack of food on Bajor, then Bajor has not reached the radical post-scarcity conditions which led to humanity choosing to do away with money.

That doesn't mean they need to use money, of course, but *something* needs to organize their society and production if scarcity is still a thing for them. In *Accession* (season four, episode 17) we learn that Bajorans no longer adhere to hereditary castes (which might have afforded enough social and economic organization). I can't think of any explicit descriptions of anything else which might suit those needs (which includes no evidence for money doing it!).

---

All quotes retrieved from chakoteya.net

[Progress](http://www.chakoteya.net/DS9/415.htm)

[Shakaar](http://www.chakoteya.net/DS9/470.htm)

[Bar Association](http://www.chakoteya.net/DS9/488.htm)

Comment: I'd say that most of your evidence concerns Latinum and the on-station/off-world economy. About the food situation on Bajor - that is some evidence, but remember Bajor was in a much more advanced state before the occupation, so post-occupation food shortages are not a good enough indication. So all in all - I'll +1 but not accept.

Answer (score 0):

> Is the reference to "Bajoran litas" sound, and based on off-screen canon documents?

Cursory Googling for the series bible turned up [this document](http://leethomson.myzen.co.uk/Star_Trek/3_Deep_Space_Nine/Star_Trek_-_Deep_Space_Nine_Bible.pdf), however it has multiple things wrong with it:

1. I can't tell if it's official, although it certainly looks like something the studio might have created. Reddit [seemed to think it was legit](https://old.reddit.com/r/DeepSpaceNine/comments/fc3bq/the_deep_space_nine_show_bible_pdf/) when they discussed it. Since I can see no obvious reason for someone to fake it, I'm going to proceed on the assumption that it is real.
2. It is dated 12 June 1992, which is well before "Emissary" entered production (in [August](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Emissary_(episode)#Production)), and it shows (e.g. Dr. Bashir is "Dr. Amoros", and he "[m]ay have an accent depending on casting"). So while it might have been canonical at some point, it probably isn't anymore. Honestly, it comes across more as a series pitch (aimed at the network) than a day-to-day reference (for the writers).
3. Skimming it, I could find no reference to the Bajoran economy, except in general terms relating to the overall condition of the planet (e.g. "[The Cardassians] have not left quietly -- in revenge for the years of terrorism, the Cardassians ravaged the planet, poisoned wells, scorched the ground[...]"). It is not OCR'd, so I was unable to do a full-text search for "lita."

My conclusion is that, if this is based on off-screen canon documents, they were probably a more recent revision, possibly issued after the episode was written (or at the very least, after they had finished casting and finalized the characters). In general, it's hard to find such documents publicly, so I'm skeptical that we will ever reach full closure on this question.

---

In my *personal opinion*, it doesn't really matter what the series bible says, because [canon is what appeared on TV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Death_of_the_Author), not what the writers and producers wanted to appear on TV. But this is obviously subjective, and I expect plenty of people to violently disagree with that assertion.

Comment: Just because it's not in the show's pitch doesn't mean it's not found elsewhere in other documents. For example in the [show script](http://www.st-minutiae.com/resources/scripts/428.txt)

Comment: @Valorum: Since the script is (mostly) line-for-line identical to what actually aired, which didn't seem to satisfy the OP, I thought I'd introduce a different source. I'm not claiming it's not found in any other documents whatsoever, just that we're not likely to find a *series bible* in particular (or any other "off-screen canon documents" - a script is not "off-screen") to support this claim.

Answer (score -2):

Bajor has yet to be a member of the federation so yes they did have money "Lita" I believe they were called. However having or Not having a currency isn't a prerequisite of Federation membership.

1. Voyager episode: Janeway purchased a Vulcan meditation lamp (and got jacked on the price) Which suggests Vulcan has a currency
2. Quark initiated repeated financial transactions with Federation/Starflee personnel on DS9 for years........
3. In TNG: Encounter at Farpoint: Doctor Crusher purchased a Roll of fabric and asked it to be charged to her "Account".
4. DS9 mentions the Bank of Bolias. Which means the Bolian homeworld (Federation member) has a financial institution.

Comment: Note:  "lita" was in the question.

Comment: Humankind, particularly on Earth, doesn't use money, but is that a feature (whether or not a hard requirement) of Federation membership?

Comment: There's no reason why Federation membership would be a precondition to a money-based economy. Also, you're repeating information I gave in the question.

Comment: I think the federation is happy to have any culture as long as they aren't warring on other cultures or doing something insanely cruel.

Comment: @MarkRogers very specific rules and a lengthy approval process have been alluded to in various episodes

Comment: Whoops, meant to say "precondition to a money-free economy".

Comment: @MarkRogers: It's happy to have any spacefaring culture whose planet is in a strategic location and which is willing to subject itself to the military dictatorship of Starfleet.

Comment: @einpoklum - Although the heavy focus on Starfleet may make it look like they are the government, in reality the government of the Federation is the Federation Council, a non-military body. It is led by the Federation president, who, while they have at times been ex-military (much like a number of countries in real life) like Jonathan Archer, need not be (like Jaresh-Inyo). The Federation is partly a UN analogue in any case: individual worlds have their own governments, like the council of United Earth, and those mentioned tend to be democratic.

Comment: Also, I am not aware of any instance of a planet being refused admission for not being in a strategic position, and in fact the vast majority of Federation member planets are well away from the Federation's principal adversaries. In fact, by most evidence, the Federation appears to be a largely socialist, democratic association.

Comment: DS9 makes this explicit. "SISKO: Do you think other Federation worlds are going to sit back and let their President be replaced by a military dictatorship?

LEYTON: Hardly a dictatorship, Ben.

SISKO: Overthrowing a legitimately elected President and giving Starfleet direct control over the government? It sounds like a dictatorship to me, and I'm sure I'm not the only one who thinks so."

Comment: @Adamant: You could say the same for Cardassia. Technically there exists a civilian government, but all large-scale intersteller activity - scientific, technical, diplomatic and military - is carried out by Starfleet. The civilian "leaders" get their information from the military, their advice from the military, and take decisions in the presence of the military. And even that's rare; usually, Starfleet just makes the decisions itself.

Comment: @einpoklum - This seems like another instance of fan-fiction to me (you are ignoring explicit descriptions of the nature of the Federation government in favor of what might make for a more interesting show). What you seem to see is a function of the bias of the show (i.e. that it is military fiction that focuses on Starfleet). On the rare occasions that we see the Council, they are usually dealing with military matters. So, unsurprisingly, in these cases they get information and advice from...the military, like any nation on Earth.

Comment: If we looked at any country you like, made a show focusing on their military over the course of centuries, and only showed their president and legislature when they took some decision relating to a war or to the military, it would look like the military had disproportionate power. Much like if we made a show focusing on a national healthcare office, and only showed the rest of the government when they made healthcare policy or during a pandemic, it would look like the healthcare system had all the power.

Comment: Some examples. 1) In DS9 ("Homefront") Sisko has to ask the Federation president to declare martial law. In a military dictatorship, they do not ask the president to declare martial during an invasion of their country, they just do it, and tell them later. 2) In TNG ("Journey's End"), fleet admiral Necheyev requests that the Federation Council hold an emergency meeting to reconsider the forced relocation of a group of Native Americans. The Council turns her down. In a military dictatorship, when the highest-ranked officer tells the civilian body to convene a meeting, they do it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108967/discussion-between-adamant-and-einpoklum).